# Escaping of MySQL queries in PHP - mysql_query() updating does nothing

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my php script for a gallery, I need to update my table.
I am using the following code, but the code does nothing:

```
mysql_query(' "update gallery_photos set photo_caption = replace(photo_caption,"\\\'","\'") "');
```

Can you tell me how to get it to work or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: `mysql_error()` should be your friend - `mysql_query(' "update gallery_photos set photo_caption = replace(photo_caption,"\\\'","\'") "') or die(mysql_error());` It will give you info about what is wrong, for example remove the outside single quotes `'`

Comment: I'd start by removing the single quotes...

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
mysql_query("UPDATE gallery_photos SET photo_caption = REPLACE(photo_caption,'\\\'','\'') ");
```

You have the escaping and ' and " mixed in a wrong way.

The thing is, there are two unescapings:  Once in PHP, then in MySQL.

So `'\\\\'` becomes "\\" in PHP and then "\" in MySQL.

And now I found out that even StackOverflow spoils it for us as it unescapes too. So to write `"\\"` here I had to write `"\\\\"` :)

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions. But unfortunately none are working.:( Right now, my code is like this  `mysql_query("update gallery_photos set photo_caption = replace( photo_caption,'\\\','\') ");`

Comment: That's wrong - `\'` turns into just `'` and then you should see a PHP error.

Comment: Try to run it in some MySQL client, eg. on console, better than trial/error through PHP which apparantly swallows the errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your suggestions. Finally I think I've got it right.
Here is what I did
`mysql_query("UPDATE gallery_photos SET photo_caption = REPLACE(photo_caption,'\\\','') ")`

Thanks,

Comment: Uhm, well, okay... good to hear it works. But translates to ... `'\','')` which removes all backslashes. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Ondra...thank you. That's also what we wanted . Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with removing single quotes at start and end.

```
mysql_query("update gallery_photos set photo_caption = replace( photo_caption,'\\\'','\'') ");
```

Answer (score 1):

try doing this

```
$que = mysql_query("select * from gallery_photos");
$fet = mysql_fetch_object($que);
$pc  = $fet->photo_caption;
$pc2 = replace($pc,"'\\\'","'\'") ;

$update = mysql_query("update gallery_photos set photo_caption='$pc2'");

if (!$update) {
  echo "Error : <br>";
  echo "".mysql_error()."";
}else {
  echo "Updated ..!!";
}
```